# SQL how do you find value that does not exist on same table?

Tags: sql, oracle

So we have columns order_number, product_name, product_number, product_type. product_type has two types, semi and finish and order number for semi starts with S and order number for finish type starts with F. Order numbers are like S123, F123. Semi and Finish order numbers exactly same except for starting part with SXXX for semi and FXXX for finish product type. They share same product name and product number but it can have 1 semi, 1 finish or just 1 semi with 1 finish product for each product number. How do I make query so I can find product that only exist in semi but not finished?

I would query

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_NUMBER
FROM TABLE A
WHERE PRODUCT_TYPE = 'SEMI';
```

but this does not show whether this product only exist in semi not finish. How do I pull this off? I can't just use PRODUCT_TYPE NOT IN ('FINISH') as their order numbers are different and only thing that matches are product name and product number.

Help. :(

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) I.e. [mcve].

Comment: A little hint: to check, if some row *exists* in the table, you can obviously try to use [`EXISTS` predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions012.htm) with desired condition in subquery.

Comment: Sample would look like s111, adiosa, 001 in order number, product name, product number in order. product number can be up to 100 but some product may exist in order number f111 which is finish product type. it only has to display semi product info that does not exist in finish product type and yes, it is oracle database. tricky part is that same product name and product number can exist in different order number. for example it can be s111, adiosa, 001 and s112, adiosa, 001 and they are both semi but under different order number.

Comment: @DC There was a link on how to prepare minimal reproducible example. Comments are not intended to be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way, SUBSTR function , removes first character ( S, F) and you can compare product numbers to see if there is any finish type:

```
SELECT
    ORDER_NUMBER
    , PRODUCT_NAME
    , PRODUCT_NUMBER
FROM
    Table1 A
WHERE
    PRODUCT_TYPE = 'SEMI'
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            Table1 F
        WHERE
            F.PRODUCT_TYPE = 'FINISH'
            AND SUBSTR( A.PRODUCT_NUMBER, 2) = SUBSTR(F.PRODUCT_NUMBER, 2)
    );
```

Comment: @Boneist you right , for some reason I was thinking  he is on SQL server , anyways , amend my query for oracle

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that uses the `COUNT()` analytic function to check for the count of SEMI and FINISH rows within each product name and number:

```
with table_a as (select 'S1' order_number, 'A' product_name, 1 product_number, 'SEMI' product_type from dual union all
                 select 'F1' order_number, 'A' product_name, 1 product_number, 'FINISH' product_type from dual union all
                 select 'S2' order_number, 'B' product_name, 2 product_number, 'SEMI' product_type from dual union all
                 select 'F3' order_number, 'C' product_name, 3 product_number, 'FINISH' product_type from dual)
select order_number,
       product_name,
       product_number,
       product_type
from   (select order_number,
               product_name,
               product_number,
               product_type,
               case when count(case when product_type = 'SEMI' then 1 end) over (partition by product_name, product_number) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end semi_present,
               case when count(case when product_type = 'FINISH' then 1 end) over (partition by product_name, product_number) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end finish_present
        from   table_a)
where  semi_present = 'Y'
and    finish_present = 'Y';

ORDER_NUMBER PRODUCT_NAME PRODUCT_NUMBER PRODUCT_TYPE
------------ ------------ -------------- ------------
S1           A                         1 SEMI
F1           A                         1 FINISH
```

I'm a bit concerned about your table structure though; this seems very denormalised (you'd usually have a table with the product information in it, with some sort of id referencing each product, and then you'd join on that product table via the id column). I hope this is a simplified version of a query on several tables that you've simplified.

P.S. In future, please supply some sample data in your question. You can see that I had to make up some data myself, which I had to guess.